# create a Pandas dataframe and name the index in one line

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'DayOfWeek': ['Mon','Fri','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Thu','Sat','Sun']
})  
dayofweek = pd.DataFrame({'count':df.DayOfWeek.value_counts()})
dayofweek.index.name = 'Id'
```

All I want to know is, how to write the last two lines of code into one? I want to name the index inside **pd.DataFrame(...)**

Comment: That's unsupported as far as I can tell as there is no param for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, very dirty but works:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]:

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame ({
   ...:     'DayOfWeek': ['Mon','Fri','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Thu','Sat','Sun']
   ...: })

In [3]: dayofweek = pd.DataFrame({'count':df.DayOfWeek.value_counts()})\
                      .reset_index()\
                      .rename(columns={'index':'Id'})\
                      .set_index('Id')

In [4]: dayofweek
Out[4]:
     count
Id
Mon      2
Thu      2
Sat      1
Tue      1
Fri      1
Sun      1
Wed      1
```

But I wouldn't suggest doing all this in one line, and it is much cleaner and readable using 2 lines.